# XNA 4.0 Additive Blending

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I am having a bit of difficulty getting Additive blending to work in XNA 4.0. I have been told that the way additive blending works in XNA 4.0 is different to how it used to be in 3.1 - which is probably what is causing me such difficulties.

I am trying to get the additive effect such that if i have red plan, a green plane and a blue plane, on top of each other and facing the user - then the net color shown on the screen would be white (Red+Green+Blue = White). However, doing this causes me to get different results. See the image below:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/824515/Untitled.png

I am using this technique to draw my planes:

```
        GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.Additive;

        foreach (EffectPass pass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
        {
            pass.Apply();

            GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, circle1, 0, points, VertexPositionColor.VertexDeclaration);
            GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, circle2, 0, points, VertexPositionColor.VertexDeclaration);
            GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, circle3, 0, points, VertexPositionColor.VertexDeclaration);
        }
```

**EDIT**: Here is a more clear example of how additive blending is currently working for me: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/824515/Untitled2.png

It seems to be adding colors well, but when in complete combination at the center, the color seems off.

Comment: Are you sure that there is a green plane? It looks like there is a red and blue plane but no green one. Furthermore, make sure that all alpha values are set to 1.

Comment: Hi Nico. Yes im sure that theres a red green and blue circle, its pretty easy to spot in the code. Im using standard XNA values like Color.Green, Color.Blue, Color.Red and Color.Black

Comment: Ah, the additional example explains it. The green you are using is not #00ff00, but #008000, which is a dark green.

Comment: You could use `Color.FromNonPremultiplied(rrr,ggg,bbb,aaa)` or `new Color(){R = 255; G = 255; B = 255; A = 255;}` constructions for more obvious colors.

Comment: You want `Color.Lime`. As Nico says, `Color.Green` is not full intensity green.

Comment: Great, ill try that out as soon as i get home from work :)!